# Does my wifi connection have anything to do with lag on multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am at a campsite right now that has wifi and the connection is not very good. I was wondering if this affects the lag produced while playing multiplayer on minecraft.

Comment: Most likely.  If you really want to know you should probably give us additional information.  What are your PC specs?  Does Minecraft run without lag in singleplayer?  Do you know anything about the network (i.e. download/upload speed)?  Any mods installed?

Comment: Yes;  `Lag` or `Latency` is caused by dropped packets.  If you have a poor connection then you have lots of dropped packets.

Comment: Why would you be using a computer while camping? Jus sayin...

Answer (score 2):

The speed and connectivity strength of the internet connection **will** most definitely affect latency when playing on multiplayer, this applies to pretty much any game with multiplayer.

Keep in mind however that this kind of latency causes things like blocks coming back temporarily after you break them, mobs and other players appearing to teleport, and containers taking a while to open; "Framerate lag", in which your screen jitters and controlling where you are looking can become hard, is a different issue which will **not** be affected by anything to do with the connection, but rather the computer itself and the render settings you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have great signal strength, great connection speed, and are physically-close to the server, I would still expect a campsite-WiFi to be lagging for video games.

The issue is that over WiFi, **only one person can be transmitting at a time** *(including the access-point)*.  If two devices try to transmit at once, they both stop, wait a random amount of time, and try again.  At busy hotspots with several people connected at once, this invariably leads to lots of dropped packets, which equals horrendous lag.

My suggestion when in a place with crowded WiFi signals *(Starbucks, Internet cafe, pretty much everywhere in big cities, etc)* would be to always use wired if possible for gaming.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of lag you get. If you are getting high framerates but getting teleported back, typing things in chat and having to wait a long time for them to show up and maybe even people pausing in one spot, it is Server Lag. This is where either your internet or the servers connection is having problems. Another type of lag is Client Lag, where your PC is struggling to handle the game and the frames are low, but no server lag syntoms.